# We would like to call an event which is observed from admin as well as from API, which area I should use?

Tags: magento2, api, area

Please Help me on this point i'm new in thie area ,

I would like to call an event which is observed from admin side as well as from API, in which area I should put my `events.xml` an dmy `observer` file ,please help me on this.

Comment: Just inside the etc folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For Frontend Only `Namespace\Module\etc\frontend\events.xml`
>
> For Admin Only `Namespace\Module\etc\adminhtml\events.xml`
>
> For All `Namespace\Module\etc\events.xml`

Comment: where we put for only in rest api? inside the webrest_api/events.xml or etc/events.xml

Answer (score 1):

Please Look at here,

you can create observer for admin like this

> project/app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="custom_form_build_after">
        <observer name="Vendor_Module::AdditionalFormFieldBannerTitle"
              instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Admin\FormBuild" />
    </event>
</config>
```

You can create your observer like this one

> project/app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/Admin/FormBuild.php

And add your code in obeserver file.

Comment: Will the API event work if I put the observer in adminhtml?

Comment: Yahh... it's work